# BigCommerce Products API - "Product Tags" field

Tags: bigcommerce

I have been using the BgCommerce API for some time. We use the product API among others.

Using the regular admin user interface, I added some text to the "Product Tags" field for a particular product in our store. When I retrieve the product using the product API, I do not see that field / data.

Is this data missing from the API?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I heard from BigCommerce support via email on this question. I am pasting here for future searchers / readers.

===========

Unfortunately the 'product tags' is not available through the API or even from an export of your store.  That field can only be accessed manually through the Control Panel and editing the product.

If you need some data to be accessible through the API then you might try using 'Search Keywords' instead of 'Tags'.  Search Keywords serves about the same purpose as tags....there are other fields you could use as well if you are already using search keywords.